# How to unit test a method that saves to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, nsuserdefaults

As specified in the title, **how would you test a method, which saves to NSUserDefaults?**

Basically, I have a method (saveUser:), which takes a single parameter of class User, and saves firstName plus lastName to NSUserDefaults. (Also saves a few more values, but that doesn't change anything).

I searched around a bit, and it's suggested to use a class, which mimic NSUserDefaults' behavior, but I obviously can't use that, since I would have to modify my method for testing, then undo the modifications for publish.

Two solutions I came up with are:

- In setUp, save the contents of NSUserDefaults, wipe  it, then in tearDown, set the saved values back.
- Change the saveUser: method, to something like saveUser:toDefaults: then pass [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] when publishing and the mimicked UserDefaults when testing.

What do you think about either solutions, which one is better to use and why?

Comment: Um... Could you be a little more explicit about that comment?

Comment: When you (re)-implement a method in a category, it will override the existing implementation given by Foundation.framework. This means that you can have a category on NSUserDefaults that makes always returns the values you expect, and never even touches the disk.

Comment: Oh you mean to create a category for NSUserDefaults, which overwrites the setObject:forKey: and objectForKey: methods?

Comment: Exactly. It shouldn't be too difficult to just replace it with a backing dictionary.

Comment: There a multitude of problems with your suggested solution: 1) For testing, I need to import the category to the view controller class, which implements the saveUser: method, but I need to remove it for release. 2) Apple's documentation: "If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method in the original class, or a method in another category on the same class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used at runtime."

Comment: It's technically undefined, so you could result to swizzling if that makes you feel better. The category does not need to be imported at all, just as long as it is compiled with the test target it will be automagically loaded.

Comment: I've tried it, but turns out, I'm not experienced enough in Obj-C to want to try method swizzling (I assume that's what I would have to to prevent the method in the category being called for keys like XCTestScopeFile, XCTest, UIDisableLegacyTextView etc. and to only the keys I want).